Authorization/Authentication in Blazor server
What is a simple and direct way to access the current users 'fields'?
For example for showing the users Roles, or his/her name, or mail etc. I want to grant access to certain content based on roles.
I am confused on this topic.
As I understand, it should be avoided to use httpcontext in a blazor server app.

Are you talking about the Authentication Claims? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/authentication-state?view=aspnetcore-9.0&pivots=server Is the problem hooking up authentication to DI or accessing the Identity object from a blazor component?

use AuthorizeView Tags with the Role definition:
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin">
<p>Welcome, Admin! You have special permissions.</p>

<AuthorizeView Roles="User">
<p>Welcome, User! Here is your dashboard.</p>

